# Hyperlink that opens in a new tab but retain focus on the current/parent page

Tags: browser

How do you format HTML A tag (when clicked) to make any browser to open it in a new tag, while retaining the focus on the current/parent page?

I know in Firefox, there is an option that says 'When I Open a link in a new tab, switch to the new tab immediately' .. but I want the opposite of this. When a new tab is opened, do not switch. Regardless I check or uncheck this option, it still behaves as I described above.

Anybody faced this before?

Cheers and thanks in advance for your answers,
Lasker

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a browser setting and you cannot override this from your code and the main thing is

***Don't do this***.

Comment: lol, I am with you .. It's just that majority of the users wishes for this. Says they prefer clicking on 5-10 then only slow go back and read them tab by tab .. 

That's why I am at loss .. haha